# create JSON with php

Tags: php, json

Sorry if this seems obvious but all the searches I am doing for this are returning complex answers and I have been struggling with this all day... I have been trying to create json data in PHP and really I want to send variables into the json data. I have not been able to do that so I followed a tutorial online and copied the code exactly yet i'm still not getting an output in my local host.. Please can somebody put me out of my misery...

```
  <?php

$jsonData = new stdClass();
$people = array(

                array(
                    'name' => 'Luci',
                     'age' => 25,
                      'sex' => 'female'
                ),
                array(
                    'name' => 'John',
                     'age' => 27,
                      'sex' => 'male')
                ),
                array(
                    'name' => 'Peter',
                     'age' =>  22,)
                      'sex' => 'male'
                )
            );



$jsonData->source = "Program Knowledge";
$jsonData->published = date('Y-m-d H:s:i;');
$jsonData->status = true;
$jsonData->people = $people;
echo json_encode($jsonData);



?>
```

eventually I was going to try

```
$var = 123456;
$jsonData->codeid = $var
```

but I need to figure out just how to get it so work with data I have typed in.

Many thanks..!!

Comment: Looks correct. what's the problem?

Comment: I get no output at all from the echo json_encode($jsonData);  not sure as to why... Thx

Comment: have you run php lint (php -l)?  You have an extra parenthesis after John 'sex => male' and Peter 'age => 22'.  Also, did you forget the semicolon after ``$jsonData->codeid = $var`` ?

Comment: ok it was simply the parenthesis issue.. It's been a long day... Thanks !!

Comment: while developing/debugging, it may be worthwhile to output errors..  ``error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', true); ``  http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php  http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php

Comment: yes great comment.. i'm new to coding in general.. Thanks again...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
                  'sex' => 'male')
                 'age' =>  22,)
```

Need to remove the parenthesis from these two lines, they're parsing errors